# On Azure, webapi+AzureAD or expressjs+passportjs

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, express

I need to build a web application on Azure, on which public users should be able to sucbscribe and log on to see and manipulate their data.

I suppose I could use webapi+AzureAD or expressjs+passportjs. Can both be used to tackle this problem in a straight and easy fashion? Are there costs involved in using AzureAD for such an application (couldn'nt quite make that out on the site).

Both C# and JS/TS are no problem.

Cheers, B.

Comment: Check out these step by step instructions: [Add sign-in to a Node.js web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web) and [Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp).

Answer (score 7):

You can do that from your ASP.NET Web application

In order to Enable a web application to authenticate with accounts, you can do that by using Azure Active Directory B2C

> FYI: Azure AD B2C enables your apps to authenticate to social
> accounts, enterprise accounts, and Azure Active Directory accounts
> using open standard protocols.

What you'll have to do is :

1. Register your web application (Create an app ID) in order to receive access tokens from the Azure AD understanding [See this Tutorial from Microsoft for a better understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#application-registration)

> PS : Make sure you're using the directory that contains your Azure AD
> B2C tenant.

2. Add your web application in the B2C Settings with the following parameters :

- Name : [Enter a Name that describes your app to consumers.]
- Include web app/web API: [Yes - Select Yes for a web app.]
- Allow implicit flow  : [Yes - Select Yes since the app uses OpenID Connect sign-in.]
- Reply URL    : [Reply URLs are endpoints where Azure AD B2C returns any
  tokens that your app requests.]
- Include native client: [Yes - If your app is a web app or No if it is not a native client].

3. Create a client password, as Azure AD uses OAuth2 authorization for client apps so they require a client ID or application ID and a client secret, client password, or application key.
4. Create policies to sign up users to access then sign in to the web app, create a sign-up or sign-in policy.
5. Create a profile editing policy to allow users to reset their user profile information on their own.
6. Create a password reset policy to enable password reset on your application. This will describe the consumer experience during password reset and the contents of tokens that the application receives on successful completion.
7. Add the following keys to the existing ones in your Web.config file in the appSettings section under the configuration part as follow and fill in the value fields:

```html
<configuration>
     <appSettings>
        <add key="ida:Tenant" value="" />
        <add key="ida:ClientId" value="" />
        <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="" />
        <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="" />
        <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="{Your RedirectUri}" />
        <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="" />
        <add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="" />
        <add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="" />
     </appSettings>
</configuration>
```